# How to use this JavaScript for multiple IDs in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

I found this script in the web: https://sebhastian.com/javascript-multiply-string/

```
let multi = 2;
let str = "Little lamb";
let multiStr = "";

while(multi > 0){
  multiStr += str
  multiStr += " ";
  multi--;
}

multiStr = multiStr.trimEnd();
console.log(multiStr); // "Little lamb Little lamb"

document.getElementById("frameText").innerHTML = multiStr;
```

and would like to ask how to use it on multiple HTML Tags with the ID "frameText". They should all have then the same textstrings. I guess its made with a for loop or so. I am absolute beginner in JavaScript.

Comment: IDs **must** be unique. Try classes if you need to repeat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot reuse an id as it is invalid HTML, and JavaScript will only ever recognize the first element with a particular id. For selecting multiple elements you should assign them all a common class name, then use [`document.querySelectorAll(".the_class")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to find them and `.forEach()` to iterate through the result set.

```js
let multi = 2;
let str = "Little lamb";
let multiStr = "";

while (multi > 0) {
  multiStr += str
  multiStr += " ";
  multi--;
}

multiStr = multiStr.trimEnd();
console.log(multiStr); // "Little lamb Little lamb"
document.querySelectorAll(".frameText").forEach(ft => ft.innerHTML = multiStr);
```

```html
<div class="frameText"></div>
<div class="frameText"></div>
<div style="padding: 2em;">
  <span class="frameText"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
let multi = 2;
let str = "Little lamb";
let arr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < multi; i++) {
  arr.push('<div class="frameText">' + str + '</div>')
}
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = arr.join("\n");
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```